# Splitting string from FOR XML PATH

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code:

```
public class TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModelResults
{
    public IEnumerable<DataModels.Training.TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModel> TrainingModuleProgressStates { get; set; }
} 

public class TrainingModuleProgressStateDataModel
{
    public IEnumerable<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> UserTrainingPoints { get; set; }
}
```

I need to split this up into:

```
public class UserTrainingPointsDataModel
{
    public virtual int InteractionType { get; set; }
    public virtual int Points { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

in my repository I get back from the database in `RawPoints`:

```
China Incentive Program,50,6,1|India - Q2 Incentive ,50,6,4|China - Q2 Incentive,50,6,5|India Incentive Program,100,8,3|India - Q2 Incentive ,100,8,4
```

each set is delimeted by the `pipe character` then the `50 = the points,6` is the interaction type and `1` is the trainingmoduleid (I don't need that pulled out anymore) and name is well, name :)

```
string RawPoints = row["RawPoints"].ToString();
foreach (var RawPoint in RawPoints)
{
    UserTrainingPointsDataModel.Name = RawPoints.Name;???
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain RawPoints in a bit more detail. Is '|' the separator for individual data points, what is "China Incentive Program", what are the numbers etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) like below:

```
string rawInput = "China Incentive Program,50,6,1|India - Q2 Incentive ,50,6,4|China -     Q2 Incentive,50,6,5|India Incentive Program,100,8,3|India - Q2 Incentive ,100,8,4";
string[] rawPoints = rawInput.Split(new char[]{'|'});

List<UserTrainingPointsDataModel> points = new List<UserTrainingPointsDataModel>();

foreach(string rawPoint in rawPoints)
{
    string[] enrty = rawPoints.Split(new char[]{','});
    var point = new UserTrainingPointDataModel();
    point.Name = entry[0];
    point.Points = entry[1];
    point.InteractionType = entry[2];

    points.Add(point);  
}
```